# How to disable the windowsinternal.composableshell.experiences.textinput.inputapp.exe which uses a dedicated GPU on a laptop?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics, nvidia-settings, dual-gpu

This app runs on a dedicated GPU instead of integrated graphics:
**windowsinternal.composableshell.experiences.textinput.inputapp.exe**

It drains my battery.
I cannot configure it via NVIDIA Control Panel.
And I don't see it in Task Manager.

How can I make it run on an integrated graphics or disable completely?

setup:
Acer Predator Helios 300 NVIDIA 1660 Ti
2019

Answer (score 1):

That is a built in application for the on-screen keyboard.

You can disable it two ways:

1. Manage > Services (System Components) > Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service -- set that to disabled
2. Find the file by right clicking it in the Task Manager and opening its location: commonly > C:\Windows\SystemApps\InputApp_randomletters -- change the permissions of the file to administrators in its properties, and then give the administrators group full access. Rename the file to .exe.bak or what ever you'd like.

It will no longer boot with windows and you will no longer need to manually kill the task. You should no longer have it running in the background. If you want it for future on-screen keyboard use, simply undue the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue, but direct solution isn't present anywhere, so here is mine:

1. Find the exe file in Task Manager on a Details tab.
2. Right click -> Open File location. You should see something like this: *C:\Windows\SystemApps\InputApp_cw5n1h2txyewy*
3. Go back to Task Manager (Details tab) and click End task. It didn't cause any issues for me so far.
4. Google "How to Get Permission From Trustedinstaller to Make Changes to Files" and acquire permissions to change *WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe*.
5. Add **.bak** postfix to the end of app directory and, optionally, after the .exe file extention.

In case it causes any issues you know where to find the original file.

Answer (score 0):

*This app does not use the GUI - it is just the On-Screen Keyboard !*

Your computer might be infected by a bitcoin miner.

I suggest to run several deep scans by well-known antivirus products,
starting with
[Malwarebytes anti-malware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

For more information see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)